# Refreshing data using Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a problem. I need that when I press a button this will automatically refresh my page putting inside it the new content. Possibly while this happens, I would like the button to do a circle animation. Thanks in advance.

```
class ViewControllerAvvisi: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate
{

var selfTable: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

@IBOutlet weak var MessageTable: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var MessageTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var SendMessage: UIButton!

var messagesArray:[String] = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.MessageTable.delegate = self
    self.MessageTable.dataSource = self

    self.MessageTable.delegate = self

    let tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "TableViewTapped")
    self.MessageTable.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    func retrieveMessages() {

        let query = PFQuery(className: "Message")

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (remoteObjects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            self.messagesArray = [String]()

            for messageObject in remoteObjects! {

                let messageText: String? = (messageObject as PFObject) ["Text"] as? String

                if messageText != nil {

                    self.messagesArray.append(messageText!)

                }
            }

            self.MessageTable.reloadData()

        }
    }

    retrieveMessages()


}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.MessageTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MessageCell")! as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.messagesArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return messagesArray.count
}

@IBAction func SendMessage(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.MessageTable.endEditing(true)

    let NewMessage: PFObject = PFObject (className: "Message")
    NewMessage["Text"] = self.MessageTextField.text

    self.MessageTextField.enabled = false
    self.SendMessage.enabled = false

    NewMessage.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success:Bool, NSError) -> Void in

            if (success == true) {

                NSLog("Message successfully saved")

        }else{

                NSLog("Message didn't save")

        }

    self.MessageTextField.enabled = true
    self.SendMessage.enabled = true
    self.MessageTextField.text = ""

    }
}

@IBAction func Refresh(sender: AnyObject) {

}
```

}

Comment: you should move the call to `self.MessageTable.reloadData()` outside of the loop, but beyond that everything looks fine. You have to call `retrieveMessages()` of course somewhere. What is your question.

Comment: The question is where and how I need to call the function so that the cells can display Parse's data.

Comment: On an unrelated note, you should use proper iOS programming conventions when naming variables. All instance variables should start with a lowercase letter, e.g. var messagesArray:[String] = [String]()

Comment: @ØyvindHauge finally someone else saying it - I got pretty tired of it by now.

Comment: @EdoardoRiggio Let's see your cellForRowAtIndexPath: function.

Comment: In your `viewDidLoad` for exmaple!? or in `viewDidAppear`? Or `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = self.MessageTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MessageCell")! as UITableViewCell
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.messagesArray[indexPath.row]
        
        return cell
    }

Comment: @EdoardoRiggio do not add code in comments, update your question (and properly format the code, of course).

Comment: Where you call your `retrieveMessages` function is really up to you and depends on how you want your app to behave.

Comment: I want that when the view shows it loads displaying the data from Parse in the cells.

Comment: Well, then put the call in `viewDidLoad`. That will make it load the data only upon loading the view controller. Note that it will not (re)load the data when you tap on "Back" on another view controller pushed on top of this one, for instance.

Comment: Last thing, now that this works, how can I refresh the UITableView using a button?

Comment: @EdoardoRiggio Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the function you created to reload the new data. Move it outside of the `viewDidLoad` function. 
Add an IBAction with the button you want to reload data and add retrieveMessages(). As you reload, new data will automatically be loaded.

```
@IBAction func refreshData(sender: AnyObject) {
retrieveMessages()
}
```

For the circle animation, I recommend using a [UIActivityIndicatorView](http://www.makemegeek.com/uiactivityindicatorview-example-ios/).